# Getting an R expression from a value (similar to enquote)

Tags: r, expression

Assume I have a value `x` which is of some (unknown) type (especially: scalar, vector or list). I would like to get the R expression representing this value. If `x == 1` then this function should simply return `expression(1)`. For `x == c(1,2))` this function should return `expression(c(1,2))`. The `enquote` function is quite near to that what I want, but not exactly.

By some playing around I found the following "solution" to my problem:

```
get_expr <- function(val) {
  tmp_expr <- enquote(val)
  tmp_expr[1] <- quote(expression())
  return(eval(tmp_expr))
}

get_expr(1) # returns expression(1)
get_expr(c(1, 2)) # returns expression(c(1, 2))
get_expr(list(x = 1)) # returns expression(list(x = 1))
```

But I think my `get_expr` function is some kind of hack. Logically, the evaluation should not be necessary.

Is there some more elegant way to do this? As far as I see, `substitute` does not really work for me, because the parameter of my `get_expr` function may be the result of an evaluation (and `substitute(eval(expr))` does not do the evaluation).

I found another way via `parse(text = deparse(val))`, but this is even more a bad hack...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`as.expression(list(...))` seems to do it:

```
> get_expr <- function(val) as.expression(list(val))
> str(get_expr(1))
  expression(1)
> str(get_expr(c(1, 2)))
  expression(c(1, 2))
> str(get_expr(list(x=1)))
  expression(list(x = 1))
> val <- list(x=1, y=2)
> str(get_expr(val))
  expression(list(x = 1, y = 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ideas, `call('expression', val)` looks much better and works for me and does not even need `enquote`.  `enquote(val)[[2]]` does not work for me, because `as.expression(enquote(val)[[2]])` returns `expression(1, 2)` (and a evaluation of this results in `2`).

Comment: EDIT: @PatrickRoocks, glad this helped.  Not sure why you use `as.expression`; I don't suggest you do so.  Re: your suggestion, note that it is pretty much equivalent to the `as.call(list(...)` version I had originally put at the end of the answer (now up front).

Comment: Well I just saw that this helps to get a oneliner - but I still need `eval` (i.e. `eval(call('expression', val))`). I want to use this result to substitute some part of another expression (i.e. `expr[1] = get_expr(..)`) without having a plenty of case distinctions. A object for which `is.expression(x) == TRUE` holds, makes life easier at this point. `as.expression(c(1,2))` returns `expression(1,2)` and does not work for me.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks, see update; let me know if this is still not what you want.  Note the function actually returns expressions now, not language objects that need to be evaluated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is definitively the shortest and most elegant solution! Seems to fully exploit that expressions are internally represented as lists.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use `substitute()`, and just need to call it a bit differently:

```
express <- function(e) substitute(expression(x), env = list(x=e))

v1 <- c(1, 2)
express(v1)
# expression(c(1, 2))

v2 <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
express(v2)
# expression(list(a = 1, b = 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this also more elegant than my idea. But still I have to eval it again to get an expression: `is.call(v1) == TRUE` and `is.expression(v1) == FALSE`. For `eval(v1)` it is the other way around and this is what works for me.

Comment: @PatrickRoocks -- Yes indeed. `express(v1)` yields a call to the function `expression()`, while `eval(express(v1))` returns the resulting expression object itself. That very subtle distinction (especially hard to grock since the printed output for both results is the same) is actually mentioned in [this section](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expression-objects) of the R-lang manual. See especially the code block following the phrase `"However, it does lead to the following bit of confusion:"`

Comment: Glad you brought this back; meant to +1 before you deleted.