# Getting an R expression from a value identical to expression(...)

Tags: r, expression

I am searching for a function `get_expr <- function(val)` returning a expression which is identical to the original expression, i.e. `identical(get_expr(c(1,2)), expression(c(1,2))` has to be true.

I asked already a question requiring a bit less: [Getting an R expression from a value (simlar to enquote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813689/getting-an-r-expression-from-a-value-simlar-to-enquote) With this it is possible to get an expression from the value which behaves in most cases like the original case - but unfortunately not in all cases. Neither in my workaorund in that question nor in the suggested solutions in the answers the statement `identical(get_expr(c(1,2)), expression(c(1,2))` evaluates to TRUE.

Example:

```
e1 <- expression(c(1,2))
get_expr <- function(val) as.expression(list(val))
e2 <- get_expr(c(1,2))
```

The console output and the evaluations of `e1` and `e2` are identical. But we get

```
> identical(e1,e2)
[1] FALSE
```

The difference seems to be the slightly different structure:

```
> e1[[1]]
c(1, 2)
> e2[[1]]
[1] 1 2
```

Now I hacked a new workaround:

```
get_expr2 <- function(val) {
  if (length(val) <= 1) {
    return(as.expression(val))
  } else {
    if (is.list(val)) op <- quote(list)
    else if (is.vector(val)) op <- quote(c)
    return(as.expression(as.call(c(list(op), as.list(val)))))
  }
}
```

Now I get that `identical(expression(c(1,2)), get_expr2(c(1,2)))` returns true.

But I am not really happy with this... Given a little bit more complicated structure this approach fails:  `identical(expression(list(1, c(1,2))), get_expr2(list(1, c(1,2))))` returns false. It seems that for my approach I have to know the structure of the value before...

I think there should be a smarter solution to convert values to their exact expression counterparts?

**Edit (21-03-15)**: What I forgot to say is that `a<-c(1,2); get_expr(a)` should also work.

A one-liner workaround which avoids plenty of cases is

```
get_expr3 <- function(x) parse(text=deparse(x))
```

But this is even more a hack...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `substitute`.

```
R> get_expr <- function(x) as.expression(substitute(x))
R> identical(get_expr(c(1,2)), expression(c(1,2)))
[1] TRUE
R> identical(expression(list(1, c(1,2))), get_expr(list(1, c(1,2))))
[1] TRUE
```

You can also use `match.call`:

```
get_expr <- function(x) as.expression(match.call()$x)
```

Warning, though: This fails on multiline expressions.

```
R> (x <- get_expr({a<-1;b<-2}))
expression({
    a <- 1
    b <- 2
})
R> (y <- expression({a<-1;b<-2}))
expression({
    a <- 1
    b <- 2
})
R> identical(x, y)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but this should also work for variables. I posted a new workaround.